# How to convert empty formats: 0x0 cell to 0x0 double - in a cell array to get correct boundingbox datastore format?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, data-science

I am working on a project where I am trying to use a boundingbox datastore in MATLAB. I have encountered an issue where my table has a 0x0 **cell** format for the empty entries, that is causing an error when trying to set up the boundingbox datastore. However, in the MATLAB example, the table has a 0x0 **double** format for its empty entries and it is working with that format.

I have tried to convert the 0x0 cell to a 0x0 double using several methods, but none of them have worked.
First, I assigned the empty entry with .. = [], after that, I assigned it with .. = double([]), and after that, with .. = {}. However, none of these statements resulted in the desired 0x0 double format.

Can someone please suggest a solution for converting the 0x0 cell to a 0x0 double in a cell array to get the correct boundingbox datastore format? Thank you!

Comment: Let's say ```c``` is your empty cell. Does ```{cell2mat(c)}``` work?

Comment: i solved with initializing it with double([]) in the very beginning, but i did not find some method to convert it . . . i will try with cell2mat now.
EDIT: cell2mat seems to be working, thanks!

Comment: Let us know, how it goes. You can also share some code, so we can understand better what you're actually trying to achieve ;)